# How can I open my Facebook app to be tested by anyone with the .apk?

Tags: android, facebook, testing

I've run into a problem with my Android app that uses the Facebook SDK for logins. It is still in development. Whenever I send the `.apk` to people that want to try it, the Facebook login flow stops at one point and informs people that the app is not set up properly.

I've checked the developer dashboard and found the problem (I suspect):

[image]

Is it possible to open my Facebook app so that anyone with the `.apk` can test the app and not only the ones I add through the app dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your app in live mode from development mode...please check attached screen shots
please follow these steps

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :D